# What is the right way to accomplish live input validation in Angular and Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to accomplish live input validation through an API call (Using Node.JS) in Angular 9.

What would be the most practical approach to this problem using the native utilities provided by Angular?

What I considered doing was to have oninput callbacks which send requests using fetch, then change the disabled attribute on my submit button accordingly - but I felt like this approach was not the best approach considering my framework selection.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax, send email value as parameter then catch it on node then run query if it has record then response it.